# Wordpress Rendered CSS Doesn't Match CSS File

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm at a loss of what's going on. Basically, I've been trying to update my style.css file. I made the updates, overwrote the style.css through FTP, but the style being rendered is the previous version of the stylesheet.

When I open style.css on through FTP and the cPanel file manager, my updated style.css is there. However, when I check it in the browser, the outdated stylesheet is being rendered. It's been a week and I've cleared the cache. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Hi. have you checked if the site is using a CDN? this is usually the problem for me even though i have purged all cache.

Comment: A CDN like Cloudflare? I don't believe it is, I just checked. A subsection of the site is using Cloudflare and I just purged the cache there as well, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to force loading of modifed css file `style.css` by adding its version at the end of the `<link>` tag : `style.css?ver=0.1.2` for example.

Each time you change the `style.css` file, you change its version and so it will be updated in browser. Even if a CDN cached it.

For example if you use child theme you can add in `functions.php` :

`$theme = wp_get_theme();
define('THEME_VERSION', $theme->Version); //gets version written in your style.css

function theme_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', [], THEME_VERSION, 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');`

And in `style.css` :

`/*
Theme Name: xxxxx
Author: xxxx
Author URI: xxx
Description: xxx
Version: 0.1.2      <- style.css version to update manually
*/`